# An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement (UPDATE)

Tags: sql-server

I suspect this issue is something to do with the MIN statement but not sure how to fix it:

```
UPDATE t1

SET t1.PrintDate = MIN(t2.[Print Date])

FROM [Data Checking].[dbo].[MonthlyReads] t1

INNER JOIN [Data Checking].[dbo].[BILLWINDOWS] t2
ON t1.MRU = t2.[MR Unit]

WHERE t2.[Print Date] > t1.[ReadingDate]
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: you can create a CTE out of your [Data Checking].[dbo].[BILLWINDOWS] that will contain the MR_Unit and the Min Print date and use that to update your [Data Checking].[dbo].[MonthlyReads]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
;WITH t2 ([MR Unit] , [Print Date]) as 
(
    SELECT [MR Unit] , MIN([Print Date])
    FROM [Data Checking].[dbo].[BILLWINDOWS]
    GROUP BY [MR Unit] 
)

UPDATE t1
SET t1.PrintDate = t2.[Print Date]
FROM [Data Checking].[dbo].[MonthlyReads] t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.MRU = t2.[MR Unit]
WHERE t2.[Print Date] > t1.[ReadingDate]
```